# how to guarantee memory reserved when running java and mysql on same server

Tags: java, mysql, memory-management, jboss

Andreas: Please don't mark this as a duplicate again. This question is actually different from the one you replaced it with and I have fortunately received a great answer from someone (who I would like to acknowledge for their help, but can't because you removed the question.

My problem is that I am runnning mysql and java (jboss actually) on the same server and I am running into memory limitations. Mysql seems to use as much memory as it can and then java can't get as much memory as it needs over time.

I've tried using -xms and -xmx (plus permsize etc.) to reserve the memory for java on startup, but this doesn't seem to do anything. I seem to recall a number of years ago that when I run a memory monitor when I start up java, I would see the memory used increase by the xms value when starting java but now it only seems to use a small portion of the xms value.

This could be resolved by either limiting the mysql memory footprint or pre-allocating the java memory. I'm looking into both options but havent found a way to do either.

This problem exists on both windows and linux. I've tried with the sun jvm versions 6, 7, and 8. Mysql is rev 5.5.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I believe that you should max -Xms = -Xmx, and add the setting -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch

Comment: Thank you Scott. This solved my problem. I'd mark this as an answer but Adreas (a mod) has incorrectly marked my quesrtion as a duplicate of another question.